# How to copy a debootstrap (chroot) directory to another computer?

Tags: debian, scp, chroot

I created an installation of Debian in a subdirectory using debootstrap on computer A.

Now I would like to transfer this installation to computer B which has a local connection but no global internet access. It was therefore easier to create the directory on computer A.

However when I try to use ssh to copy recursively the directory, I get "error" messages like

```
wheezy/dev/zero: not a regular file
wheezy/dev/ptmx: not a regular file
```

I'm not familiar with those kind of files. I guess they are related to the kernel running on computer A. Is this right?

Can I either transmit those files with scp/tar (I could not find a suitable option), or recursively copy the distribution "normal" files and then re-generate those special files with some command on computer B?

Comment: Just use `rsync -av wheezy/ user@otherhost:/path/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to preserve meta-data information:

```
cd chroot && bsdtar cf - . | nice lzop | ssh user@dest '
  cd chroot && nice lzop -d | bsdtar --numeric-owner -xpSf -'
```

(here using `lzop` to compress the stream to save bandwidth while being nice on the CPU)

Or:

```
rsync --verbose --archive --one-file-system \
      --xattrs --hard-links --numeric-ids --sparse --acls \
      chroot/ user@dest:chroot/
```